# How to grey out individual bullet points

Tags: beamer, bullets

I know how to grey out points so it greys out all except one bullet point and then keep going to other bullet points. But that isn't what I want.

What I want is for the bullet point to never be black, so that there is only a single great bullet point. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is gray
\item This is gray
\item This is black
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In other words, I want only this slide to display:

[image]

There should be no slides before or after this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `<0>` (together with `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621401/255043)).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<0> This is gray
\item<0> This is gray
\item This is black
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From beamer manual, page 194

> `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`
>
> This command allows you to specify in a quite general way how a covered item should be rendered. You can
> even specify different ways of rendering the item depending on how long it will take before this item is shown
> or for how long it has already been covered once more. The transparency effect will automatically apply to all
> colors, except for the colors in images. For images there is a workaround, see the documentation of the pgf
> package.
>
> `\setbeamercovered{⟨options⟩}`
>
> `transparent=⟨opaqueness⟩` causes covered text to be typeset in a “transparent” way. By default, this
> means that 85% of the background color is mixed into all colors or that the ⟨opaqueness⟩ of the text
> is 15%. You can specify a different ⟨percentage⟩, where 0 means “totally transparent” and 100 means
> “totally opaque.”
> Unfortunately, this value is kind of “specific” to every projector. What looks good on your screen need
> not look good during a presentation.

Comment: Yes, I know, that is what I used with my examples. The problem is that the only way I know how to use it is with [<+>] or whatever, which causes a bunch of other slides that I don't want. I want a single slide with specific bullet points greyed out.